# How to plot a 3dimensional tensor as a tube with different colors

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Let's assume that we have a numpy array `traj` with shape `(64,64,64)` and each element of this tensor may be either -1 or +1. I want to plot it into a three dimensional cube, where blue color stands for -1 and red color for +1. How I can do that?

**p.s.** *To have a physical intuition, this `traj` matrix is a three dimensional Ising model configuration, and each element of this tensor is a spin of a magnet.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a figure with a three-dimensional axes enable (`projection='3d'`) and using [ax.voxels](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.voxels) parameter `facecolors` to select the desired colors for the 1x1x1 cubes plotted on the axes.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

axes = [16, 16, 16] # change to 64
traj = np.random.choice([-1,1], axes)

alpha = 0.9
colors = np.empty(axes + [4], dtype=np.float32)
colors[traj==1] = [1, 0, 0, alpha]  # red
colors[traj==-1] = [0, 0, 1, alpha]  # blue

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.voxels(traj, facecolors=colors, edgecolors='black')
plt.show()
```

[image: cube1]